# jQuery ajax error is always "timeout" even when i'm giving wrong user/pwd

Tags: jquery

I'm calling a SOAP webservice with jQuery ajax method. It works fine if there isn't a problem, but now I'm doing some tests, for example giving a wrong user name/password and the error that I receive is not the expected 401: Unauthorized. The call waits until the timeout is exceeded and then returns a timeout error...

I've tried my web service with wrong credentials on SOAPUI and I get the Unauthorized instant error message. My javascript call is the following:

```js
$.ajax({
    url : soapURL,
    type : 'POST',
    username : settings.get('user'),
    password : settings.get('pwd'),
    timeout : '30000',
    dataType : 'xml',
    data : soapReq,
    success : soapSuccess,
    error : soapError,
    contentType : 'text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"',
    beforeSend : function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    },
    complete : function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
});
```

And here the error callback function:

```js
function soapError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('Ajax error: ' + textStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some more research about this problem. There is a lot of people having problems doing AJAX calls with basic authentication + phonegap doing cross domain calls, and I didn't found a perfect solution to solve this.

But thanks to this [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es&fromgroups#!searchin/phonegap/401/phonegap/HkS-8QG-A40/SJkRDlIuUhMJ), at least I discovered that with a synchronous call to any service, I can validate the user and password and keep using asynchronous after this.

Another possible solution is to change the server response after a 401 error, but I wasn't allowed to modify this.